# How to set administrative user in Mysql 5.7

Tags: security, mysql-5.7

I am trying to run a scan from Nessus against Mysql 5.7 database

I am getting the following error:

Ensure Only Administrative Users Have Full Database Access 'mysql.user'

Perform the following actions to remediate this setting:

1. Enumerate non-administrative users resulting from the audit procedure
2. For each non-administrative user, use the REVOKE statement to remove privileges as appropriate

   Policy Value: regex:".+", "root"

   (Default): "root", "localhost""user1", "%""user2", "%""user1", "localhost""user2", "localhost""user3", "localhost""user3", "%"

Why is it flagging the root user as a Non-Administrative Users?

My application uses user1 and user2.

Is there a way I can set user1 and user2 as Administrative Users?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Yes I am familiar with how to create accounts in MySQL.